# Docker mongo and mongo-express connection issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container, docker-image, mongo-express

When I'm trying to connect to mongo-express I'm getting a connection issue, kind of error

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=anirban
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=mypass
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports: 
      - "8081:8081"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=anirban
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=mypass
```

The above is my docker-compose.yaml

so after this, in my docker desktop > mongo-express process I'm getting this page,
[Running container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ2dS.png)

Then after 1 minute approx, I'm getting the localhost:8081 up and running in my browser,

```
2024-01-21 13:15:53 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
2024-01-21 13:15:53 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
2024-01-21 13:15:59 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
2024-01-21 13:15:59 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
2024-01-21 13:16:05 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
2024-01-21 13:16:05 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
2024-01-21 13:15:48 Waiting for mongo:27017...
2024-01-21 13:15:54 Sun Jan 21 07:45:54 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (2/10)
2024-01-21 13:16:00 Sun Jan 21 07:46:00 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (3/10)
2024-01-21 13:16:06 Sun Jan 21 07:46:06 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (4/10)
2024-01-21 13:16:11 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
2024-01-21 13:16:11 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
2024-01-21 13:16:12 Sun Jan 21 07:46:12 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (5/10)
2024-01-21 13:16:17 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
2024-01-21 13:16:17 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
2024-01-21 13:16:18 Sun Jan 21 07:46:18 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (6/10)
2024-01-21 13:16:23 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
2024-01-21 13:16:23 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
2024-01-21 13:16:24 Sun Jan 21 07:46:24 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (7/10)
2024-01-21 13:16:29 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
2024-01-21 13:16:29 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
2024-01-21 13:16:30 Sun Jan 21 07:46:30 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (8/10)
2024-01-21 13:16:35 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
2024-01-21 13:16:35 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
2024-01-21 13:16:36 Sun Jan 21 07:46:36 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (9/10)
2024-01-21 13:16:41 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
2024-01-21 13:16:41 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
2024-01-21 13:16:42 Sun Jan 21 07:46:42 UTC 2024 retrying to connect to mongo:27017 (10/10)
2024-01-21 13:16:47 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: mongo: Try again
2024-01-21 13:16:47 /docker-entrypoint.sh: line 15: /dev/tcp/mongo/27017: Invalid argument
2024-01-21 13:16:48 No custom config.js found, loading config.default.js
2024-01-21 13:16:48 Welcome to mongo-express 1.0.2
2024-01-21 13:16:48 ------------------------
2024-01-21 13:16:48 
2024-01-21 13:16:48 
2024-01-21 13:16:49 Server is open to allow connections from anyone (0.0.0.0)
2024-01-21 13:16:49 basicAuth credentials are "admin:pass", it is recommended you change this in your config.js!
2024-01-21 13:16:49 Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
```

Is it normal that it's taking much time to load, or there's some issue because there are many invalid arguments in the Running Container picture.

I've been getting this since the beginning, I just started Docker

Comment: Same issue. No idea so far.

Answer (score 0):

Is it like your mongo container was not started yet and mongo express already trying to connect it? Then you should try to add dependency like this:

```
mongo-express:
 ...
 depends_on:
      - mongodb
```